# Excel VBA: copy cell "address" message content to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that will locate the blank cells in Column A and will highlight them in red. Then, a msgbox will display the location of the blank cells using "Address". For example it will show: "No Value, in $A$15".

```
Sub CeldassinData()

Dim i As Long, r As Range, coltoSearch As String

coltoSearch = "A"

For i = 1 To Range(coltoSearch & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range(coltoSearch & i)
    If Len(r.Value) = 0 Then
         r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' Red
          r.Select
          MsgBox "No Value, in " & r.Address
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

**I need help with:**
For each message that will pop and find a blank cell, I want to copy, for example, the value "$A$15" shown in the message and paste it in the Column A of another sheet in the same workbook.

I would really appreciate it if someone helps me with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the msgbox put this:

```
Sheets("Log").Range("A" & Sheets("Log").Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).Row).offset(1,0).formula = r.Address
```

Make sure you have a sheet in there called Log and it will populate

Comment: Hey I need help with something else, maybe you could help me. I have a Column in Excel with a header called "Role". I want all the rows in this column to have the number 3 in it. Therefore, first, I want to find the value in these rows and if the value is not 3 to highlight the row and show this message: "Role for Students should be 3 in". Following my previous example I have this code but it does not work for this:

Comment: Sub role() Dim i As Long, r As Range, coltoSearch As String

    coltoSearch = "F"

    For i = 1 To Range(coltoSearch & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range(coltoSearch & i)
        If Len(r.Value) = 23 Then
             r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' Red
              r.Select
              MsgBox "Role for Students should be 3 in" & r.Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub